# What car is appropriate for a fundraiser to drive

Tags: charity, donation

My partner and I are looking at new cars.   I am a software developer, she is a fundraiser for a non-profit organization  and we share a vehicle to commute work.

Recently we started looking for new cars, specifically at an electric Tesla 3. It's  in our price range but she has  concerns about showing up at her organisation's work events/fundraisers in a flashy car, perhaps giving the appearance that  they overpay their employees, thereby discouraging donations. Is this something people consider when thinking about making a donation?

Comment: "Is this something people consider when thinking about making a donation?"  If I saw her car, then yes I would consider it.  Honda (Civic or Accord) and Toyota (Camry or Accord) are your basic "speaks quality but unobtrusive" cars.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble trying to understand how this fits as a personal finance and money question, although it is an interesting question. I'm not sure if there's going to be a good answer that isn't opinion based, though. Personally, I would think "good for them, they have a nice car." But, anecdotally, I know a wealthy landlord with a garage full of expensive cars who also keeps a fairly junky 25 year old Saab to drive when he is trying to avoid the "rich landlord" image. So I guess it's a thing for some people.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about what people think about each other belong on interpersonal.SE.

Comment: Where would be a more appropriate place to ask? I understand this is a hard question to fit in a category.

Comment: It may depend on the charity. If it's a charity devoted to environmental causes it may be considered in a _positive_ light.  And plenty of independently wealthy people do charity work.

Comment: Unrelated but once a builder arrived on my door in a top of the range BMW. I was like WTH. And then when he quoted for the work, I realized how he could afford a top of the range BMW. Similarly I would believe for a charity(non-profit), it might give people the idea of where the money is not going.

Comment: @RonJohn If you stick square brackets [ ] around interpersonal.se, the system turns it into the appropriate link, like so: [interpersonal.se].

Comment: I wouldn't call a Tesla 3 "flashy". "Noticeable", given their relative rareness, but not flashy.

Comment: What does she think would be appropriate?  And why not just have two cars?

Comment: @DumbCoder the problem with assumptions like that is that you gloss over the potential that someone drives a nice car because they're hard working and successful (vs because they're somehow taking advantage of people). My brother is a builder, he drives a nice BMW. But it's because he's been working his bottom off, 24x7, for a few decades, doing high quality work that he is appropriately compensated for.

Comment: For random non-profit employee, I'd suspect that partner/family has money. If the CEO/upper level management has flashy cars, then I wonder what the overhead costs are of the non-profit.

Comment: @dwizum The problem is what the prospective customer thinks. Car too cheap - he is not successful, therefore no good. Car too expensive - customer thinks who is paying for this?

Comment: @dwizum Your brother isn't a good example to quote. You are and will be biased towards him about him being hardworking and a honest builder. Ask a builder who isn't a personal friend. And builders where I live always come in a white van, because that is where they store their tools and go to work in. A builder driving a BMW to a customer engagement isn't a builder at all. No builder needs to carry their work tools in a top range BMW, unless they intend to show off.